# Getting JSON Data and parse it into using Decodables. But i am getting some error "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format"

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

I am getting json response from the server and after that i will decode this json data into my model class. But it shows error "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format". I am using this feature first time in iOS. I actually don't know how to resolve this error. I already add model class code and getting data code below. Please check.

### Model Class

```
struct PlacesResult: Decodable {
    let html_attributions: [String]?
    let next_page_token: String?
    let results : [Result]?
}

struct Result: Decodable {
    let formatted_address: String?
    let geometry: Geometry?
    let icon: String?
    let id: Int?
    let name: String?
    var photos: [Photos]?
    let place_id: String?
    let rating: String?
    let types: [String]?
    let user_ratings_total: Int?
}

struct Geometry: Decodable {
    let location: Location?
    let viewport: ViewPort?
}

struct Location: Decodable {
    let lat: String?
    let lng: String?
}

struct ViewPort: Decodable {
    let northeast: NorthEast?
    let southwest: SouthWest?
}

struct NorthEast: Decodable {
    let lat: String?
    let lng: String?
}

struct SouthWest: Decodable {
    let lat: String?
    let lng: String?
}

struct Photos: Decodable {
    var height: Int?
    var width: Int?
    var photo_reference: String?
    var html_attributions: [String]?
}
```

### Decode Json Data

```
if let data = responseObject.dataObject as? Data {

do {
    let placesData = try JSONDecoder().decode(PlacesResult.self, from: data)
    print(placesData.next_page_token)
    //print(placesData.results?.count)
   }
catch {
        print("Error : \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
}
```

Error:

> Error : typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "geometry", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "location", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "lat", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: You also need to show (in your question, as text) a relevant snapshot of the actual JSON you are trying to parse.

Comment: And only make a struct property optional if the JSON may not have that value.

Comment: Please give your JSON response.

Comment: **Never ever** print `error.localizedDescription` in a `JSONDecoder` catch block because you get this generic and pretty meaningless error message. Print always only the `error` instance (`print("Error:", error)`). It tells you exactly what's wrong and even where.

Answer (score 1):

The added `DecodingError` message is very comprehensive. It contains the type of the error, the key path and the description.

To clarify the structure this is the message split in multiple lines

```
Error : typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(
        codingPath:   
            [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), 
               _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0),
             CodingKeys(stringValue: "geometry", intValue: nil),
             CodingKeys(stringValue: "location", intValue: nil), 
             CodingKeys(stringValue: "lat", intValue: nil)], 
         debugDescription: 
             "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

- The error type at the beginning is a type mismatch.
- The `codingPath` describes the key path. It points to key `lat` in dictionary for key `location` in dictionary for key `geometry` in the first item of the array for key `results` (aka `results[0].geometry.location.lat`)
- The `debugDescription` describes the error. ***Expected*** is the proposed wrong type, ***found*** is the actual  type.
  So the value of `lat` is not a string, it's a number, most likely `Double`

**All** JSON keys and string values are wrapped in double quotes so the `String` type can be recognized immediately.